# Access Control for Swift Extensions

Tags: swift, access-control, swift-extensions

Swift Programming Language has this to say about access control for extension:

> You can extend a class, structure, or enumeration in any access
>   context in which the class, structure, or enumeration is available.
>   Any type members added in an extension have the same default access
>   level as type members declared in the original type being extended. If
>   you extend a public or internal type, any new type members you add
>   will have a default access level of internal. If you extend a private
>   type, any new type members you add will have a default access level of
>   private.
>
> Alternatively, you can mark an extension with an explicit access level
>   modifier (for example, private extension) to set a new default access
>   level for all members defined within the extension. This new default
>   can still be overridden within the extension for individual type
>   members.

I don't fully understand the above statement.  Is it saying the following:

```
public struct Test { }

extension Test {
  // 1. This will be default to internal because Test is public?
  var prop: String { return "" }
}

public extension Test {
  // 2. This will have access level of public because extension is marked public?
  var prop2: String { return "" }

extension Test {
  // 3. Is this the same as the above public extension example?
  public var prop2: String { return "" }
}
```

Comment: I think the definition of `prop2` is conflicting with Apple Document: `If you extend a public or internal type, any new type members you add will have a default access level of internal. ` Or am I understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your understanding is almost correct.

A more interesting way to put your scenario 3 would be

```
extension Test {
  // The extension has access control internal, because of what the docs say:
  //
  // > If you extend a public or internal type, any new type members you add
  // > will have a default access level of internal.
  //
  // Despite the extension being internal, this member is private because it's
  // declared explicitly here.
  private var prop2: String { return "" }
}
```

as well as

```
internal extension Test {
  // The compiler will give a waning here, why would you define something public
  // in an internal extension?
  public var prop2: String { return "" }
}
```

Also you might find interesting that if your class, struct or enum is `internal`, you will not be able to define a `public` extension. The same goes for a `private` class, struct or enum, for which you cannot define a `public` or `internal` extension.

Comment: "// The exension has the same access control of Test". Shouldn't it be internal, as per "If you extend a public or internal type, any new type members you add will have a default access level of internal. "

Comment: Thanks @BangOperator, you are indeed correct. I've updated the answer.